# Relationship between terminal clients

Tags: windows-terminal-services

I am new to Windows terminal services.

If two terminal clients log into Windows terminal services, can these 2 clients communicate between each other?

Do they or can they have permanent identities such as IP addresses, machine name etc so that a program on 'Client A' can send TCP/IP packets to 'Client B'.

Can Client A remember Client B's address so that when they go offline and connect back, they should be able to identify each other and start talking again?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do some reading on this. For the questions, I assume you mean the two clients are logging into the same single Terminal Server.

1. Not sure what you mean - if they can run an IM program, they can communicate that way, same as if they were running the IM program on their own desktops. There's nothing in TS that gives them a chat window, unless "net send" works on the server in question.
2. The two users are on the same TS machine; they have "sessions" on it, they are using whatever IP address(es) are on the TS server. And those aren't permanent; the sessions only last as long as the users are logged in.
3. Since they don't have addresses, and the session numbers change between logins, I think the answer is "no", but I have no idea what you really mean by "start talking again."

Answer (score 0):

The clients will likely have the Same IP as the terminal server and they wont be able to send TCP/IP packets to each other, the client machines will have different IP's and can generally communicate with each other however that communication would be happening outside of the terminal server connection.

Think of terminal server as remote desktop as that is all it is, it will be like you are logged onto the server itself in your own environment because the other client will be connected to the same server its probably unlikely that you  can communicate via TCP/IP between sessions.

What do you actually need to do?

Comment: Terminal Server *is* remote desktop. It's not an analogy, that's what it *is*.